# Problems writing data with empty lines to a .htaccess File on Ubuntu WSL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have problems with writing data to a .htaccess file on a Ubuntu WSL with PHP.

The following is the case:

If i replace the empty lines of the following string:

```
#BEGIN BLOCK1
#END BLOCK1



#BEGIN BLOCK2
#END BLOCK2
```

with the following PHP Script:

`$text = preg_replace("/([\n]*|[\n]+)[\s\t]*[\n]+/", "\n", $content);`

and write it to a .htaccess file on a Ubuntu Apache WSL - it looks like the same string with empty lines as before.

But if i write it to another file with the same script - the empty lines are removed as expected.

I checked the permissions of the .htaccess - they are at 777. And i also checked "\r\n" and "\n" lines - but nothing works ...

i hope that somebody can explain me why i have empty lines even after replacement.

Comment: Please post all relevant code/your full attempt, example data, expected result from that data and what currently happens (we need details, incl. full error messages, if any.) Also read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Does writing a simple "hello" in .htaccess work at all?

Comment: your pattern could be simplified as `\s*\n+` that would match exactly the same things. which code do you use to overwrite the file content ?